# Select div options as youtube suggestions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know how can I select options of a suggestion divs with keyboard up/down arrows, as in youtube, when you type any key and the suggestion appears you can select an option with the keyboards arrows. I have a textbox and I have a "suggestion" div bellow. How can I do it? (Im not using jQuery autocomplete)

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the [jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). Here's an example from the documentation which illustrates how you could turn a standard `<input>` element into an Autocomplete box using a specified data source:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags" />
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

In this example the data is hardcoded into the HTML but the plugin also supports retrieving the autocomplete values [`using a remote datasource`](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote).

So it's up to you to play with it and come back on StackOverflow if you encounter some specific problems with the implementation (without forgetting to show your progress so far of course).

Comment: As I wrote in my message im not using autocomplete jQuery plugin. The problem is that I don't want to compare any data, I want to add automatically words and do it selectable with arrows

Comment: So you want to achieve the same functionality without using a plugin? Well, then roll up your sleeves and prepare to write a ton of javascript. You will have to subscribe for the onkeyup, onkeydown events of the input field, detect what the user typed in, send an AJAX request to your server to retrieve the corresponding suggested values, build dynamically a new `<div>` below the input field containing the suggested values, then subscribe to the `onkeydown` event and detect whether the user typed the up or down arrow in and depending in this provide a visual animation changing the selection ...

Comment: ... it's basically what the existing plugins such as `autoComplete` already provide as an out-of-the-box functionality. Good luck with the implementation. Once you have some code, don't hesitate to come back here and ask more specific question if you encounter some problems with your implementation. Hopefully you haven't expected that for a question such as `How do I implement an Autocomplete box as Youtube` you would get a full blown javascript and CSS implementation here.

Comment: Yes, I have prepared the div and the values, now i want to see any sample about that. i want to know if there is any suggestion list demo that is not necessary to compare values...

Comment: If you have done that, don't hesitate to show your progress so far and explain what exactly isn't working with your code, what difficulties you have encountered with it. Also when asking questions about HTML/javascript and CSS and is considered a very good practice to provide a working http://jsfiddle.net demo exemplifying your progress so that other people could more easily test your code and provide you with guidance.

Comment: is only a div and providing data via $("#id").html(data).fadeIn()... I think that is not a great advance for the community. But I want to know if there is any function or demo where I can convert the div in selectable <li>'s or something similar, and accessible via keywords. Anyway thank for your help!

Comment: No, there's no such function built-in javascript nor jQuery. You will have to write it yourself if you don't want to use existing plugins.